# Customize color of UISlider in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am using a slider in my app. It has the default color black I want to change it to brown.

I followed the 'Changing sliders appearance in SDK help'

I used the code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sliderBrown"
                                                 ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *minimumTrackImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

[voiceLevelSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minimumTrackImg
                              forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

but in this case my slider just disappeared.

Please enlighten me on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the [UICatalog example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html). You can find a lot of info about creating different controls, including custom controls.

Comment: excellent suggestion - answered alot of questions for me! thnx